# How to update oracle database table in c# with variable from text.box

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

When I click on update button I dont get any errors but my table isnt updated.

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            OracleConnection cnn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            cnn.Open();

            oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("UPDATE KUPAC SET NAZIVKUPCA = :NAZIVKUPCA, PIB = :PIB, MATICNIBROJ = :MATICNIBROJ, ZIRORACUN = :ZIRORACUN, EMAIL = :EMAIL WHERE KUPACID = :KUPACID", cnn);


            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("@KUPACID", Convert.ToInt32(txtKupacId.Text));
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("@NAZIVKUPCA", txtNazivKupca.Text);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("@PIB", txtPIB.Text);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("@MATICNIBROJ", txtJMBG.Text);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("@ZIRORACUN", txtZiroRacun.Text);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", txtEmail.Text);
            int result = oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Kupac uspesno izmenjen");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Greska prilikom izmena u bazi." + exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

        OsveziKupce();
        ObrisiPolja();
    }
```

I get message "Kupac uspesno izmenjen", which means that table should be updated, but nothing happens

Comment: I am not sure what your code is doing but just want to know if commit is executed after update?

Comment: my code should be updating oracle database table from textboxes where I put values... When I click on button I get message: ,,user is updated" but it isnt when I check it

Comment: I think you have to bind by name. Try: oracleCommand.BindByName = true;

Comment: Sir, where should I put that command?